# Can't download libs from Pentaho Nexus

Tags: maven, pentaho

I need to download several Pentaho libs (cpf-core & cpf-pentaho), but Pentaho Nexus site is not working:

[image]

If I use the public version (https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/), I stil get the same message. Is there any problem?

Comment: Why not get them from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pentaho/cpf-core?repo=pentaho-omni ?

Comment: Thanks! Well... that is what i've tried durings these days, but it didn't work... Until today! For me, the server was down and that was the real problem.

Comment: @Llorieb i think this might help https://community.hitachivantara.com/discussion/publicnexuspentahoorg-unavailable